# Kakeya crossed-needles problem

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

The [Kakeya needle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakeya_set) asks for the
minimum area planar region in which one can completely turn around a line segment through
a series of translations and rotations. There is no minimum: There are "Kakeya needle sets" of arbitrarily small area.

I ask the same question but for a rigid plus-sign, two equal-length segments
at $90^\circ$ sharing their midpoints, forming a $+$ shape.
Because it seems difficult to achieve $360^\circ$ rotation using the type of
spikey sets so effective for a single needle, I'm wondering if the answer here
might be just a disk?

[image: KakeyaPlus]

Comment: Do you know the answer for three lines at equal angles?

Comment: @VilleSalo: No, I don't. Nor for a `T`-shape. I thought perhaps the `+` is the easiest to settle.

Answer (score 20):

I do not know if the minimal area needed to rotate the + is that of the smallest disk containing it. However, I do know that it cannot be done with arbitrarily small area.

This is a special case of a beautiful general theorem by Csörnyei, Héra, and Laczkovich, Theorem 1.2 of [Closed sets with the Kakeya property](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00286.pdf).

I will try to translate the relevant piece of their theorem to have a bit less jargon, but the paper is very clear.

Theorem: Let $A$ be a non-empty, closed, connected subset of the plane. Suppose that there exists a non-trivial rigid motion $m$ of the plane such that $A$ can be continuously moved through rigid motions to $m(A)$ inside sets of arbitrarily small area. Then $A$ must be a line segment, a half-line, a full line, a circular arc, a circle, or a singleton.

There may be a simple argument for the plus sign that also gives your conjectured bound; I haven't thought about it. Maybe looking at their proof would provide it.

Comment: Wow, that's an amazing theorem! It still seems possible that there is a set of area smaller than the disk area, but not arbitrarily small.

Comment: Welcome to [mathoverflow.se]! Please note that the formatting here works a bit different than you're used to, see the [Help Center](/help/formatting) for details.

Comment: I do not get this. If "full line" means "unbounded straight line", how can it be moved within a set of arbitrarily small area unless it is never rotated? And if it is never rotated, then it is simply not moved at all!

Comment: @user21820 I believe the point is that the motion $m$ can be a nontrivial translation of the plane parallel to the line. Then, of course, the line never changes along $m$, but $m$ _is_ a nontrivial rigid motion of the plane.

Comment: @LukasMiaskiwskyi: I see. That makes sense, thanks!